# Sharepoint frontend and SQL 2008 (SSRS) on different servers

Tags: reporting-services

This is my first foray into Sharepoint (WSS 3.0) and I'm trying to get SSRS reports running on the front end Sharepoint system, whereas now they are on a different server.  I am not familiar with the concept of farms but I have a feeling I will need to be in order to get this working.

When I say 'front end' I mean the site we can access remotely outside our intranet.

So I have this...

Server 1)
Sharepoint Front End (works fine, but cannot view reports)

Server 2)
SQL Reporting Services, 2008 R1 (full version), in Sharepoint integrated mode (works fine, but not accessible from front end)

In Server 1 Central Administration, I tried setting "Grant Database Access" to the report database on Server 2, but got the error "Unable to connect to the Report Server WMI provider" so I'm thinking this was not the correct solution.

Does anyone know how these servers are supposed to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Sharepoint 2007, I'd suggest you just use the Reporting server web parts to display these reports. These web parts allows you to specify the URL of where your report is :

http://reportserver/reports/myreport.aspx for example.

You can read more on the subject here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159772.aspx